# ViewPager Glide

Tags: android-viewpager, glide

Имеется ViewPager(Slide) с тремя картинками. Glide загружает эти картинки и отображает во ViewPager и кэширует. Но если я на сервере, допустим, меняю "Картинку 1" с тем же названием и той же ссылкой, то в приложении все равно остается та же закэшерованная картинка

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private String [] image = {"http://rgho.st/7hDcbyT2F/image.png",
        "http://familyguy.fox-fan.ru/photos/3.jpg",
        "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JKogH2VCCoY/V_aZWCFsmtI/AAAAAAAABAA/Lu6D13VXGSMMnYFO8T8-pKDeqbkHhNRAwCLcB/s320/VideoThumbail.PNG"};



public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
   layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bulding_layout, null);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPager);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(image[position])
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(imageView);






    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager)container;
    vp.addView(view,0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager)container;
    View view = (View)object;
    vp.removeView(view);
}



 public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(viewPagerAds.getCurrentItem() == 0){
                    viewPagerAds.setCurrentItem(1);
                }else if(viewPagerAds.getCurrentItem() == 1){
                    viewPagerAds.setCurrentItem(2);
                }else viewPagerAds.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Перед загрузкой очищайте кэш

```
Picasso.with(this).invalidate(url);
```